# Powerpoint transparency animation

Tags: macos, animation, transparency, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

I have a placed vector image and text made in Powerpoint. I need both to animate fade from 50% to 100%. Transparency function in Powerpoint seems to only work from 100% to 50%. Does anyone know of a way to reverse this function or another way of doing somethign that seems so simple.

Comment: Which version of PowerPoint?

Comment: Long time ago I made a tutorial on how to make a picture show with sliding color images.Maybe you can use that technique. Watch the embedded video to see what it does. ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/72115-powerpoint-create-picture-show.html

Comment: wbeard52 I am using Powerpoint 2011 for Mac

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

- Add a shape and duplicate it.
- The first shape make it transparent at 50%
- The second shape leave it at 100% and place it on top of the transparent one. Give the second shape a fade in animation.

*You can do the same with images, but you either have to set the image as background to a shape and set the transparency or you have to make the image transparent in another image editing software.*